# How to use the {{ $labels.instance }} syntax within the Prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, go-templates

Given the Prometheus query syntax below for a annotation field "currentNumber" in the alert.yaml

```
currentNumber: "{{ with query \"max_over_time(json_exporter_resultList__0::currentDeviceNumber[1h])\" -}}
    {{- . | first | value -}}
    {{- end }}"
```

It works but might query an incorrect value if there are metrics from multiple instances.

So, I have to query by the label as syntax below which works perfectly on Prometheus web console.

```
max_over_time(json_exporter_resultList__0::currentDeviceNumber{instance='test'}[1h])
```

However, I couldn't get it right to be used within the "with query" syntax with the {{ $label.instance }} syntax.

```
currentNumber: "{{ with query \"max_over_time(json_exporter_resultList__0::currentDeviceNumber{instance='{{ $label.instance }}'}[1h])\" -}}
    {{- . | first | value -}}
    {{- end }}"
```

Either the queried value is empty or syntax is error by escaping the ' or changing to use ` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to examples in [Prometheus' documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_examples/#advanced-iteration) you should use `printf` to prepare query if it uses labels of your current alert, and feed result into `query` using pipe.

In your example this should result in something like this:

```golang
currentNumber: "{{ with printf "max_over_time(json_exporter_resultList__0::currentDeviceNumber{instance='%s'}[1h])" .Labels.instance | query  -}}
    {{- . | first | value -}}
{{- end }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, markalex. You are a lifesaver! Didn't realize the usage of the printf with pipeline to prepare the statement for the query syntax. In my case, the double quote of the query statement needs to be escaped by backslash. {{ with printf \"max_over_time(json_exporter_resultList__0::currentDeviceNumber{instance='%s'}[1h])\" .Labels.instance | query  -}}

Comment: @Bruce, not sure on the quote escapement. Are you using it in something like helm? Or why do you need this escapement? Official documentation doesn't have it, and I cannot recall from experience need for this too.

Comment: Mark, I am using the expression just in the prometheus alert.yml. If the escapement is not available, got this error caller=manager.go:1032 level=error component="rule manager" msg="loading groups failed" err="alert.yml: yaml: line 36: did not find expected key". The version of Prometheus is v2.45.1.